# Using ListView in Stack on top of FlutterMap widget - Map is not showing

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I would like to implement horizontal scrallable ListView widget on top of FlutterMap widget.

When I am using most of widgets, they are displayed in Stack (on top of) that FlutterMap, but as soon as I use ListView, due to unknown height of children items, height is 100% and map is not interactive. When I use `shrinkWrap` and items are centered, map handle gestures on sides, but it shrinks to content only horizontally.

I tried to use Text widget or Container etc and it works. Only with ListView there is that issue where map cannot handle gestures. I tried to wrap ListView to SizedBox, use shrinkWrap, without luck.
Goal is having a map and at bottom part horizontal scrollable icons/boxes, but for now I need anything generated by ListView. Here is a code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      FlutterMap(
        mapController: _mapController,
        options: MapOptions(
          center: currentLatLng,
          zoom: _defaultZoomLevel,
        ),
        children: [
          TileLayer(
            minZoom: 2,
            maxZoom: 18,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            subdomains: const ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Positioned.fill(
          child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemExtent: 70.0,
                  children: [
                    const Chip(label: Text('data')),
                    const Chip(label: Text('data')),
                    const Chip(label: Text('data')),
                  ])))
    ]);
  }
```

I do believe it has to be something with renderer, but I am just not able to find out what. Any help would be appreciate!

EDIT:
Here is fixed solution:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: [
      FlutterMap(
        mapController: _mapController,
        options: MapOptions(
          center: currentLatLng,
          zoom: _defaultZoomLevel,
        ),
        children: [
          TileLayer(
            minZoom: 2,
            maxZoom: 18,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            subdomains: const ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 50.0,
            child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemExtent: 70.0,
                children: [
                  const Chip(label: Text('data')),
                  const Chip(label: Text('data')),
                  const Chip(label: Text('data')),
                ]),
          ))
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the bug you were talking about above. Maybe you should try to clean cache and rerun the project again, maybe you have version problems, or you just didn't show the whole code.

Comment: Map can be rendered for first time, but cannot interact with it. I found out that issue is tha height of ListView is 100% and since it is on top of map, touch gesture is not handled. And ListView has to has 100% because rendering cannot be sure of height of children widgets. Edited question

Comment: you can limit the height of your Listview with a Container() or Sizedbox(). After that you should be able to interact with your map.

Comment: Thank you Mike, interesting is that I was trying it put into sizedbox, but maybe there was other issue. Now I endup having Stack with `fit: StackFit.expand` and that overlay widget is wrapped into Align->SizedBox -> ListView and it behaves correctly. Feel free to create your answer for that and I will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `Listview` in `Sizedbox` and try to set a height for your `ListView`.